# How to import libraries from another (local) directory?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

Why I mean with that title is:

I have some generated code which I am using in my Angular application.

Currently, I am installing this as a package using npm, but this makes problem with my whole deployment setup.

Therefore I'd like to move this code to something like `src/vendor/my-generated-library`.

I can do that but all my imports then would look something like

```
import {MyObject} from '../../../../vendor/my-generated-library';
```

Is there a way to define `src/vendor` as some sort of additional library-root, such as `node_modules`, such that all my imports can stay as they currently are?

```
import {MyObject} from 'my-generated-library';
```

Comment: Hm, what about npm link?

Comment: Or just add the dependence to npm dependencies like “vendor”: “file:../../path/to/you/genlibrary

Comment: You can do it via npm install /absolute/path/to/genlibrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply modify your `package.json` to have this library as dependency and point the path as your src's directory. something like

```
"my-generated-library": "./somepath/vendor/my-generated-library"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, indeed, that works. Didn't know we can do that. Thank you!